# Partitioned view not working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, partitioned-view

I am trying to get partitioned views to work, and still see query optimizer scanning both tables. Here is my script:

```
CREATE TABLE A(DataDate [date] NOT NULL CHECK(datepart(yy, DataDate) <= 2010)) 

CREATE TABLE B(DataDate [date] NOT NULL CHECK(datepart(yy, DataDate) > 2010))

CREATE VIEW V AS SELECT * FROM A UNION ALL SELECT * FROM B 

select * from V where datepart(yy, DataDate) = 2009
```

But when I look at the execution plan I see that both table **A** and table **B** were scanned and the  "Number of Executions" for both tables is 1. I would expect table **A** to have `Number of Executions = 1`, and table **B** to have `Number of Executions = 0`. I am on `SQL Server 2012`.

Can somebody clarify how this is supposed to work? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is supposed to work like this:

```
CREATE TABLE A(DataDate [date] NOT NULL CHECK(DataDate < '20110101'));

CREATE TABLE B(DataDate [date] NOT NULL CHECK(DataDate >= '20110101'));
go

CREATE VIEW V AS SELECT * FROM A UNION ALL SELECT * FROM B 
go

select * from V where DataDate >= '20090101' and DataDate < '20100101';
go
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I was using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190019(v=sql.105).aspx as a guide, which is based on DATEPART, and that was my problem.

Comment: @user1044169 - it's a very confused example, that one. You'll note that there are *multiple* check constraints on `May1998sales`, and the actual one used for partitioning is on `OrderMonth` (`CHECK (OrderMonth = 5)`). The one on `OrderDate` is a red herring.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation in [CREATE VIEW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956), on Partitioned Views, when discussing the constraints that must exist on the base tables:

> Constraint C1 defined on table T1 must be of the following form:

```
C1 ::= < simple_interval > [ OR < simple_interval > OR ...]
< simple_interval > :: = 
< col > { < | > | <= | >= | = < value >} 
| < col > BETWEEN < value1 > AND < value2 >
| < col > IN ( value_list )
| < col > { > | >= } < value1 > AND
< col > { < | <= } < value2 >
```

Your constraints are not of this form, and thus it's not eligible to be a partitioned view. You need simple constraints, such as the ones that @Remus has shown, and not ones that call on functions.

---

And, of course, the other advice found anywhere you look up Partitioned Views in BOL:

> The preferred method for partitioning data local to one server is through partitioned tables. For more information, see [Partitioned Tables and Indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787).

Partitioned *tables* have been the preferred method of partitioning since their introduction in SQL Server 2005.